# Redmine, can't see new Issue Status

Tags: status, redmine

I added a new status to Redmine, but I can't see it in the dropdown list, even when manager is logged in.
What can be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 29):

Got it working.
All you need to do is open Administration -> Workflow and check out "Only display statuses that are used by this tracker", only this way you can see all new statuses to edit in wf.

Answer (score 5):

Did you enable the new status in the workflow for any tracker (Administration -> Workflow)? You need to specify what statuses are allowed for a tracker type.